# C# - Oracle stored procedure with output recordset NOT RefCusror

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-type

Long time lurker, first time posting...

I have an issue that I can't seem to find a solution.
I have a web service in C# calling a Procedure inside an Oracle Package. 
The procedure returns n output parameters + a recordset. 
I'm trying to find a way to fetch the recordset as an output parameter WITHOUT using a RefCursor (please do not judge this choise...I just need an alternative).

I've tried using a Table of [table_name]%RowType output parameter, but I can't find a suitable C# OracleType and I constantly get an invalid parameter error.

To summarize,
is there any other way to fetch a redordset directly(not through a refCursor) as a Procedure's output parameter? If so, what's its data type when calling it from C#?

Comment: Just use 'var result = ... ' you can then see what it returns

Comment: Maybe you can transform your entire result into an XML string and return this.

Comment: That's a very nice idea, but I'm looking for a more direct approach on this matter without the need for extra data parsing

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever been successful using a procedure that returns a refcursor or sys_refcursor as described [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php).

Seeing as these are dynamic types it's hard to imagine a requirement that could not be met by this.